# Minimize in Access 2007 Macro

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have an Access 2003 project that I am trying to open in Access 2007. The first action I take is a Macro with the action Minimize, followed by executing a module that opens my starting form. This is so the user only see the opening form and not any of the access tables. However when I open the project in Access 2007, the minimize does not work, the tables show. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

Ensure macros are enabled in the trust center (under access options in the main menu) in Access 2007

Ensure your minimize macro is named AutoExec in Access 2003

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, it did not help.